# LongListSelector with two ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I use this code to add ListBox to my app:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="searchList" Margin="0,72,0,0" SelectionChanged="DidPressSelectSearchList">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Now my issue is that i want to use two kind of `ItemTemplate`, because there is two ways i show data to the user:

1) Array of Strings

2) Array of objects(2 Strings)

Any help how i can use the list to show two kind of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in WP7 is with a Template Selector. 
[Like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector)

Though I cant test it right now, WP8 should support the DataType property on the DataTemplate class, which means you can define implicit Data Templates for each data type and skip the selector altogether.